# M.2 Drives not appearing after reset of Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, software-raid, dell-precision, nvme, m.2

I recently, mistakenly uninstalled a driver which forced me to completely reset my machine. I have a Dell Precision Tower 5810 running Windows 10. I have a standard internal hard drive as the C: drive.

I also have 4 Samsung 970 PRO NVMe M.2 drives mounted on a Aplicata Quad M.2 NVMe SSD PCIe x16 Adapter ([more information here](http://www.aplicata.com/quattro-410/)). They are setup in a software RAID 10 equivalent using built in Windows 10 tools (storage spaces and drive management). At the time of the reset, I had the drives and the Aplicata mount out of the machine. All of their data is backed up, as I did not expect these drives to work immediately when I plugged them in, assuming information relating to the software RAID would be stored on the C:/, which I reset completely.

The problem I am having, however, is that I cannot find a trace of the drives anywhere. I don't see them in disk management, I don't see them in the BIOS under the Drives tab. I need to reformat the drives, reestablish my software RAID, and move the backed up files to them. But I cannot find a trace of them on my system.

I have tried leaving only 1 at a time mounted in the Aplicata, and have tried with all 4.

Any insights would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: From an employee at Aplicata: "The adapter is a pass through for all the SSD signals (no circuitry between the SSD and host). ". In case this is important.

Comment: When you performed the Reset, did you choose to keep all personal files or keep nothing? If you simply rebooted your machine you should use a different term then "Reset" means something entirely since you are running Windows 10.

Comment: I did a complete reset, keeping nothing.

Comment: It should also be noted that none of the drives show up in Samsung Magician, either.